# Will DDR2 memory work with DM pins tied to LOW, if no data masking is required?

Tags: memory, ddr2

I have a board with the LDM and UDM pins swapped.  If they are tied to low, will the memory still 'work', given that data is always written to mod 4 addresses and always using all 4 bytes?

Memory is [Micron MT47H32M16HR-25E](http://download.micron.com/pdf/datasheets/dram/ddr2/512MbDDR2.pdf).

Comment: My brief scan of the datasheet suggests that your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Since the read and writes aren't dependent on those signals, you are correct. Specifically there is no requirement that the signals transition; they can stay at a static enabled

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation @brian, right now this answer is a bit closer to a comment.